# Does JS have "if (let foo ...) {...}"? / How can I scope a variable declaration to inside an if statement including the condition part?

Tags: javascript

Lots of times I am needing to declare a variable just for a truthy if statement.
For example:

```
let entry;
entry = entries.find(....);
if (entry) {
   // use entry
}

// i dont need entry here
```

I tried combintations similar to `for (let i=0; ...)` like this:

```
if (let entry = entries.find(....)) {
   // user entry
}
```

But it's not working. If I use `var` instead of `let` it works but the variable it hoisted so its not limited to that if statement block.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in `{ }`.

Comment: Oh wow thanks Pointy!! I never did this before in js a labeled/unlabeled block!

Comment: Clojure has an `if-let`. That would be handy for cases like this. You could probably make a function that does this effect if you find yourself needing this a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `let` creates a block scope, you need to create another block around it to limit its scope.

A block statement is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets.

```
let x = 1;
{
  let x = 2;
}
console.log(x); // logs 1
```

Alternatively you can use an  Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
(function () {
    let entry = 6;

    if (entry) {
        console.log(entry);
    }
 })()
// Variable entry is not accessible from the outside scope
```

Answer (score 9):

This is probably an idiom that was never made for JS, but just for kicks, here's a helper that could be used, although the other answer is probably more correct.

This was inspired by Clojure's `when-let` that does exactly what you're looking for, but doesn't require a function since it's a macro:

```
function ifDo (maybeTrueVal, doF) {
    if (maybeTrueVal) {
        doF(maybeTrueVal);
    }
}

ifDo(entries.find(....), (truthyVal) => {
    console.log(truthyVal);
});
```

Comment: It might not be idiomatic, but exactly what I was looking for, coming from clojure :-)

Comment: downside to this (I'm pretty sure) is that it could prevent you from using some control flow how you want, such as breaking out of a loop, or returning from the function.

Comment: @starball Yes, this would prevent statements like `return` and `break` from working correctly if you wanted to conditionally `break` or `return` from an enclosing loop/funcrtion.

Answer (score 2):

At the time being, you can work around this by declaring the variable before the if statement, and wrapping that declaration and the if statement in a block. Ex.

```js
{
  let foo = getValue();
  if (foo) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

See also https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Declarations-in-Conditionals, which proposes syntax allowing this:

```js
if (let foo = getValue()) {
  // ...
}
```