# Restricting the scope of an assignment in conditional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

The following code pushes all the points below the limit into `data`, until `getPoint` returns `null`.

```
while ((x = getPoint()) && x < limit) {
   data.push(x)
}

console.log(x, 'x should be undefined here')
```

In this particular case I use an assignment in a conditional, I know it looks ugly, but the question focuses on `x` which is not local to the block. I tried to place a `let` there, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to restrict the scope of `x` inside the `while` statement?

Another working implementation would be this one, but in this case I double the test on `x`:

```
do {
  let x = getPoint() 
  if (x && x < limit) {
    data.push(x)
  } 
} while(x && x < limit)
```

or

```
while (true) {
  let x = getPoint()
  if (!x || x >= limit) {
    break;
  }
  data.push(x)
}
```

or

```
function* getPointIterator(limit) {
  let x = getPoint()
  while(x && x < limit) {
    yield x;
  }
}

data.push(...getPointIterator(limit))
```

Comment: You can try use `{}` block for restricting lexical scope

Comment: alternatively, use a `for` loop: `for (let x; (x = getPoint()) && x < limit;) {}`

Comment: @Hamms, you're right it is better with a `for` loop

Comment: @DennisVash How would you restrict the lexical scope of a global variable with `{}`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348427/does-js-have-if-let-foo-how-can-i-scope-a-variable-declaration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider to change the while loop with a for loop:

```js
var limit = 3;
var r = 2;
var data = [];

function getPoint() {
    return r++;
}


for (let x=0; (x = getPoint()) && x < limit;) {
    data.push(x)
}

console.log(typeof(x) === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : x, 'x should be undefined here')
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Code block `{...}`

You can use a **“bare”** code block `{…}` to isolate variables into a **“local scope”**.

```
{
  // do some job with local variables that should not be seen outside

  let message = "Hello";

  alert(message); // Hello
}

alert(message); // Error: message is not defined
```

For your case:

```
const limit = 3;
let y = 0;
const getPoint = () => y++;

{
    let x = 0;
    while ((x = getPoint()) && x < limit) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
console.log(x, 'x should be undefined here');
```

The code outside of the block (or inside another script) doesn’t see variables inside the block, because the block has its **own Lexical Environment.**

### 2. IIFE `(function {...})`

You can use so-called **“immediately-invoked function expressions”** (abbreviated as *IIFE*) used for this purpose.

They look like this:

```
 (function() {

  let message = "Hello";

  alert(message); // Hello

})();
```

For your case:

```
const limit = 3;
let y = 0;
const getPoint = () => y++;

(function () {
    let x = 0;
    while ((x = getPoint()) && x < limit) {
        console.log(x);
    }
})();
console.log(x, 'x should be undefined here');
```

Here a *Function Expression* is created and immediately called. So the code executes right away and has its own private variables.

The **Function Expression** is wrapped with brackets `(function {...})`, because when JavaScript meets **"function"** in the main code flow, it understands it as the start of a *Function Declaration*.

Comment: @DennisVash Why don't you change your answer to show that?

Comment: @Barmar added both cases