# i can't assign a variable in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've just started learning JavaScript and I have a question about the `if` statement: why when I assign a variable inside the `if` I don't need to add `var` before it and when I assign it outside the `if`, I must add `var`.
So, mainly the question is: why I can't add `var` inside the `if` like this

```
if (var number = 5) {
   document.write("successful");
} else {
   document.write("failed");
}
```

and if i didn't add a var it assign the variable to the value like this

```
if (number = 5) {
    document.write("successful");
} else {
    document.write("failed");
}
```

I know it's a simple question but it got me confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scope at let to a if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348427/scope-at-let-to-a-if-statement)

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript does not support block level scoping** and this means that declaring a variable inside of a block structure like a `if` or a `for` loop, does not restrict that variable to the statement.

Remember that you need to **declare** a variable before **assigning** it to something.

- Declaration of a variable

```
var x;
```

- Assignment of a variable

```
x = 'variable x is a string that was previously declared';
```

This means that in your first not syntactically correct example, you are trying to define a variable inside a statement that, instead, should check the truth of that variable against something else. And this seems actually what you are trying to do in your second example, except that you have to use a double equals `==` (**comparison**) or triple equals `===` (**strict equality** or **identity**).

At this point, you may want to understand the differences in using `=`, `==` and `===`.

- Using single equals you are declaring or assigning something to a variable

```
var a = 55;
```

- Using double equals you are comparing two different things (variables, numbers, strings, etc)

```
a == 55 /* In this case the output will be true if you have declared the previous variable */
```

- Using triple equals you are not only comparing the content of the variable but also the type of that variable

```
a === 55 /* Will return true as the content is the same and also the type (they are both numbers) */

a === '55' /* Will return false, as you are comparing a number against a string */
```

Said that, remember also that JavaScript has two variables **scopes**: global and local.

- Any variable declared outside of a function belongs to the **global scope**, and is therefore accessible from anywhere in your code.

```
var b = 'hello world';

function test() {
    console.log(b);
}

test();

/* Output will be:
hello world
*/
```

- Each function has its own scope, and any variable declared within that function is only **accessible locally** from that function and any nested functions.

```
var b = 'hello world';

function test() {
    var b = 'Wonderful World';
    console.log(b);
}

console.log(b);
test();
console.log(b);

/* Output will be:
hello world
Wonderful World
hello world
*/
```

Comment: i didn't mean inside the block {} i meant inside the parentheses ()  if i tried to assign a variable inside them without var i won't get an error like this  `if (number = 5){ document.write("successful"); } else{ document.write("failed"); }` but i can't assign it as a var or let or const like this `if (var number = 5){ document.write("successful"); } else{ document.write("failed"); }`

Comment: Again, writing `if (number = 5)` is NOT syntactically correct. Avoid declaring variables inside a check statement, you have to use it to compare 2 things.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what you are trying to do is this:

```
var number = 4;
if (number == 5){
    document.write("successful");
}
else{
    document.write("failed");
}
```

Comment: hello i don't need to type (var number = 4;) it will not give me any error if i declare it in if

Comment: ``if (number == 5){
    document.write("successful");
}
else{
    document.write("failed");
}`` the program won't give me any error and it will write successful

Comment: If I execute your code, I get this message: `error: Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined`. How do you execute it ?

Comment: sorry i meant `if (number = 5){ document.write("successful"); } else{ document.write("failed"); }`

Comment: So the question is why ? What is your purpose ? What are your trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because var means that you declare a variable. However you can't declare a variable in an if condition. You can just assign values to previously declared variables in the condition. It is Javascript's syntax.